# A for loop to add a total row to a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop

I have a list of dataframes [list of dataframes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPBAE.png). Each dataframe (`dat[[1]]`) has 6 columns:

1. First column has the project name
2. Second column has 6 categories (badminton, football, soccer, basketball, baseball, swimming)
3. Then target, weekly, gap and completion rate which is a % of how many goals were completed during that time

My goal is to add a Grand total row to the bottom of each of the tables in the list. I wrote this code in R but it only adds a grand total row to the first element in a list. please, help me to add a grand total row to the rest of the elements in a list. Thank you!

```
 for (d in 1:length(dat)){
    dat[[d]]%<>% bind_rows(summarize_all(dat[[d]], funs(if(is.numeric(.)) sum(.) else "Grand Total")))
    dat[[d]]%<>% cbind(dat[[d]], col_names)
  }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to save calculated values within data itself? Best practice is to not store calculations but run as needed at report stage.

Comment: I am trying to automate a report, R is new to me and this is what made sense to me.

Comment: Hi! It is difficult to reproduce your problem without having a little excerpt of your data, what we call [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If you can put the first lines of your processed data we could help you with much more quality.